# Why does position property affect the display property?

Tags: css

1. In the given code, in `div.text` section when I assign `position: absolute` then the `display: block` property becomes inactive and I have to set `width: 100%` to align the text in the center. What's the reason?
2. Why do I have to first set the position property to `relative` of the container in order to set the position of the child element to `absolute`? If I don't set the `position: relative` of the parent container then the element is positioned with respect to the body tag. Why?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div.first-div {
  background-image: url(louis-lo-275893-unsplash.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

div.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

span.border {
  color: cornsilk;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="first-div">
    <div class="text">
      <span class="border">Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I have to first set the position property...

The default value of the `position` is `static`, which displays elements as they appear, or in other words: not positioned. `Absolute` positioning will place an element `relative` to its first positioned (not `static`) ancestor element. If nothing is positioned, the `<body>` or topmost element is it. That's where the need for setting parent `position` to `relative` comes from. Going from `static` to `relative` makes it "positioned" and now child object with `absolute` position will tie to its ancestor and not `<body>`. *from https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp*

> ...I have to set width: 100% to align the text in the center. What's the reason?

When you remove `position: absolute` style from `div.text` it does not affect `display:block` (`block`, as opposed to `inline`, means the element doesn't "like" being next to other elements) `<div>s` or divisions are block elements and `<span>s` are inline. So setting `display:block` on any `<div>` is redundant. Setting the width to 100% makes the `<div>` occupy the entire line instead of a default: as little space as necessary. Not specifying width doesn't cancel text centering, it's just centered inside the `<div>` that fits perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. And also when i disable position: relative (inside div.first-div) in the browser then opacity property becomes inactive on 'Hello'. could you tell why?

Comment: Sorry, I could not recreate changing the opacity by changing the position. What browser&version are you using?

Comment: https://ibb.co/GWd7RWH In this ss, since div is a block element should it not occupy all the space on the sides. and in styles, the second part i.e. div { ... } why is display: block inactive despite of me specifying that the display: block?

Comment: It should not occupy all horizontal space. Being block means that the next element will be placed on a new line* (unless other css) instead of to the right of it. The "second" div style is a part of a user agent stylesheet which is the default fallback if nothing is specified. In this case, it's not inactive but is overwritten by div.text display:block style. It just shows you which style rule takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

1.The reason behind given width in absolute position is the default position of absolute and relative is left,top so we have to specify the width to perform any center alignment action. also no need to give display block property to the class, it's by default block, if your are performing some toggle action then you have to apply that property to any css.

2. When ever we are applying  absolute position to child div it is necessary to assign the relative position to the parent, because of doing this we are restrict the are for absolute position action, if we are not applying position relative property to the parent, child css have some top, bottom, left, right property then it will show some where in body of html.

For better understanding of css position property please follow the attached link to understand the nature of position property.
[enter link description here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26?gi=5ce6dcd288b8)